# GIF super slow on Quick Look

Tags: macos, quicklook

Mountain Lion got animated GIF support for Quick Look, but the animations show as slowmotion. It renders very slow even if the GIF has a fast frame rate. Is there any way to improve this or replace the Quick Look functionality with something that works better?

Comment: With which mac do you get this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Any. I have used 13 and 15 MacBook Pro (different models), also MacBook Pro Retinas and my own MacBook Air 13 (this year's model).

Comment: Could you attach such a GIF for us to test?

Comment: He's right, compare gif between QuickLook and a web browser. They are significantly slower on quicklook. (Running on a late 2012 iMac)

Comment: Yes, I'm not talking about a particular GIF but any GIF. They all look quick and smoth on any browser, like Safari or Chrome, but really really slow on Quick Look.

Comment: By the way, great news! OS X Mavericks fixes this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Mavericks, somehow, solves this issue.